# How to represent tree with sharing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I would like to represent a "tree" of the following shape in Haskell:

```
   /\                            
  /\/\
 /\/\/\
/\/\/\/\
` ` ` ` `
```

/ and \ are the branches and ` the leaves.  You can see that starting at any node, following the left path, then the right gets you to the same node as following the right path then the left.  You should be able to label the leaves, apply a function of the two decendants at each node, and propagate this information to the root in O(n^2) time.  My naive efforts are giving me an exponential run time.  Any hints?

Comment: I do not quite get the purpose of the tree. Would it be possible to use a list as well? If your leaves are labeled from left to right with values v1 to v5 could you as well represent your tree by a list [v1, ..., v5]? For example, to look up a value you only have to count the number of right steps in your path to identify the correct value in the list. In other words, if you label a leaf do you want to keep the sharing structure? That is, if we label the leaf at left, left, left, right, is the leaf at left, left, right, left supposed to change as well?

Comment: Jan, I want to label the interior nodes as well, based on the values at the leaves, and then efficiently look up this information at a future point in the program.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is certainly possible to construct a tree with shared nodes. For example, we could just define:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

and then carefully construct a value of this type as in

```
tree :: Tree Int
tree = Node t1 t2
  where
    t1 = Node t3 t4
    t2 = Node t4 t5
    t3 = Leaf 2
    t4 = Leaf 3
    t5 = Leaf 5
```

to achieve sharing of subtrees (in this case `t4`).

However, as this form of sharing is not observable in Haskell, it is very hard to maintain: for example if you traverse a tree to relabel its leaves

```
relabel :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
relabel f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
relabel f (Node l r) = Node (relabel f l) (relabel f r)
```

you loose sharing. Also, when doing a bottom-up computation such as

```
sum :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sum (Leaf n) = n
sum (Node l r) = sum l + sum r
```

you end up not taking advantage of sharing and possibly duplicate work.

To overcome these problems, you can make sharing explicit (and hence observable) by encoding your trees in a graph-like manner:

```
type Ptr = Int
data Tree' a = Leaf a | Node Ptr Ptr
data Tree a = Tree {root :: Ptr, env :: Map Ptr (Tree' a)}
```

The tree from the example above can now be written as

```
tree :: Tree Int
tree = Tree {root = 0, env = fromList ts}
  where
    ts = [(0, Node 1 2), (1, Node 3 4), (2, Node 4 5),
          (3, Leaf 2), (4, Leaf 3), (5, Leaf 5)]
```

The price to pay is that functions that traverse these structures are somewhat cumbersome to write, but we can now define for example a relabeling function that preserves sharing

```
relabel :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
relabel f (Tree root env) = Tree root (fmap g env)
  where
    g (Leaf x)   = Leaf (f x)
    g (Node l r) = Node l r
```

and a `sum` function that doesn't duplicate work when the tree has shared nodes:

```
sum :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sum (Tree root env) = fromJust (lookup root env')
  where
    env' = fmap f env
    f (Leaf n) = n
    f (Node l r) = fromJust (lookup l env') + fromJust (lookup r env')
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan!  Your first form was what I had initially, and as you state it's hard to maintain the sharing.  I was hoping to have a version that didn't require explicit labels (Ints in your case) but perhaps that's impossible.

Comment: At this year's Dutch FP Day, I have talked about how to get the best of both worlds: still write your functions as if you were traversing trees (using catamorphisms and the like), while having the benefits of observable sharing. The slides for that talk can be found on my website: http://www.holdermans.nl/talks/assets/nlfp11.pdf. A paper on this subject is in preparation.

Comment: @dblhelix - a couple years later, did that paper ever materialize?

Comment: @ajp Good question. I do have an advanced draft sitting around here, waiting to be finished. I'll need to assess whether that story still makes sense. In the meanwhile, some interesting things have been published about this topic; check out, for instance, the work by Bruno Oliveira and others.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can represent it simply as a list of leaves and apply the function level by level until you're down to one value, i.e. something like this:

```
type Tree a = [a]

propagate :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a
propagate f xs =
  case zipWith f xs (tail xs) of
    [x] -> x
    xs' -> propagate f xs'
```

Comment: Certainly, but I would also like to keep the intermediate nodes available for inspection, and to navigate efficiently from one node to its descendants.