# Non-tree data structures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Making tree like data structures is relatively easy in Haskell. However, what if I want a structure like the following:

```
    A (root)
   / \
  B   C
 / \ / \
D   E   F
```

So if I traverse down the structure through B to update E, the returned new updated structure also has E updated if I traverse through C.

Could someone give me some hints about how to achieve this? You can assume there are no loops.

Comment: Should equality determine identity? More verbosely, suppose `D`, `E`, and `F` are all `Int`s. If `D` and `F` both happen to have the value 5, when I update one, should the other update?

Comment: @icktoofay: Why should `D` and `F` be correlated in any way? That's not indicated by his example graph at all.

Comment: @icktoofay: If you update A->B->E, then A->C->E should update. That's the only correlation.

Comment: @Zeta: Haskell doesn't have a built-in notion of identity, so it's necessary to establish one, be it by equality or by explicitly using `STRef`s or something similar. It was to some degree designed to make the reader think about how they would determine whether two objects were identical in a language with referential transparency like Haskell.

Comment: @icktoofay: Ah, I get your point, but I guess that equality should only determine equality in this example, not identity.

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411755/how-to-represent-tree-with-sharing-in-haskell) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would flatten the data structure to an array, and operate on this instead:

```
import Data.Array

type Tree = Array Int -- Bounds should start at (1) and go to sum [1..n]
data TreeTraverse = TLeft TreeTraverse | TRight TreeTraverse | TStop
```

Given some traverse directions (left, right, stop), it's easy to see that if we go left, we simply add the current level to our position, and if we go right, we also add the current position plus one:

```
getPosition :: TreeTraverse -> Int
getPosition = getPosition' 1 1
  where 
    getPosition' level pos (TLeft ts)  = getPosition' (level+1) (pos+level) ts
    getPosition' level pos (TRight ts) = getPosition' (level+1) (pos+level + 1) ts
    getPosition' _     pos (TStop)     = pos
```

In your case, you want to traverse either ABE or ACE:

```
traverseABE = TLeft $ TRight TStop
traverseACE = TRight $ TLeft TStop
```

Since we already now how to get the position of your element, and `Data.Array` provides some functions to set/get specific elements, we can use the following functions to get/set tree values:

```
getElem :: TreeTraverse -> Tree a -> a
getElem tt t = t ! getPosition tt

setElem :: TreeTraverse -> Tree a -> a -> Tree a
setElem tt t x = t // [(getPosition tt, x)]
```

To complete the code, lets use your example:

```
example = "ABCDEF"

exampleTree :: Tree Char
exampleTree = listArray (1, length example) example
```

And put everything to [action](http://ideone.com/TG4RpU):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ "Traversing from A -> B -> E: " ++ [getElem traverseABE exampleTree]
  putStrLn $ "Traversing from A -> C -> E: " ++ [getElem traverseACE exampleTree]
  putStrLn $ "exampleTree: " ++ show exampleTree ++ "\n"

  putStrLn $ "Setting element from A -> B -> E to 'X', "
  let newTree = setElem traverseABE exampleTree 'X'
  putStrLn $ "but show via A -> C -> E: " ++ [getElem traverseACE newTree]
  putStrLn $ "newTree: " ++ show newTree ++ "\n"
```

Note that this is most-likely not the best way to do this, but the first thing that I had in mind.

Comment: Am I missing something, or does this only work for the specific example? Say, for example, I wanted the left child of B (aka D) to be the same as the right child of C (aka F) and instead have two distinct Es. It seems to me that it links the two Es only by coincidence.

Comment: @icktoofay: That depends on how one reads the example. It's not clear whether he wants a general "many nodes can point to another node" (for which you clearly need identity), or "at any level q, the node n should point to n + q and n + q + 1" (for which you don't need identity). I assume that you have answered the question with respect to the first statement, while I have taken the latter one.

Comment: @zeta: Yes, you're right, this is supposed to be general.

To you think I could use the ST monad but hide it in runST so it has a pure interface? Don't need a full example (though it would be nice) just would like to know whether I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've established identity, it can be done.

But first you must establish identity.

In many languages, values can be distinct from each other, but equal. In Python, for example:

```py
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [1]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

You want to update E in one branch of the tree, and also update all other elements for which that element *is* E. But Haskell is referentially transparent: it has no notion of things being the same object; only equality, and even that is not applicable for every object.

One way you could do this is equality.  Say this was your tree:

```
    __A__
   /     \
  B       C
 / \     / \
1   2   2   3
```

Then we could go through the tree and update all the 2s to, say, four. But this isn't exactly what you want in some cases.

In Haskell, if you want to update one thing in multiple places, you'll have to be explicit about what *is* and *isn't* the same thing. Another way you could deal with this is to tag each different value with a unique integer, and use that integer to determine identity:

```
              ____________A___________
             /                        \
            B                          C
           / \                        / \
(id=1)"foo"   (id=2)"bar"  (id=2)"bar"   (id=3)"baz"
```

Then we could update all values with an identity of 2. Accidental collisions cannot be a problem, as there can be no collisions except those that are intentional.

This is essentially what [`STRef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-STRef.html) and [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-IORef.html) do, except they hoist the actual value into the monad's state and hide the identities from you. The only downside of using these is you'll need to make much of your code monadic, but you're probably not going to get away from that easily whatever you do. (*Modifying* values rather than replacing them is an inherently effectful thing to do.)

The structure you gave was not specified in much detail so it's impossible to tailor an example to your use case, but here's a simple example using [the `ST` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) and a [`Tree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Tree.html):

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Tree
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Data.STRef

createInitialTree :: ST s (Tree (STRef s String))
createInitialTree = do
  [a, b, c, d, e, f] <- mapM newSTRef ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
  return $ Node a [ Node b [Node d [], Node e []]
                  , Node c [Node e [], Node f []]
                  ]

dereferenceTree :: Tree (STRef s a) -> ST s (Tree a)
dereferenceTree = traverse readSTRef

test :: ST s (Tree String, Tree String)
test = do
  tree <- createInitialTree
  before <- dereferenceTree tree
  let leftE = subForest (subForest tree !! 0) !! 1
  writeSTRef (rootLabel leftE) "new"  -- look ma, single update!
  after <- dereferenceTree tree
  return (before, after)

main = do
  let (before, after) = runST test
  putStrLn $ drawTree before
  putStrLn $ drawTree after
```

Observe that although we only explicitly modified the value of the left E value, it changed on the right side, too, as desired.

---

I should note that these are not the only ways. There are probably many other solutions to this same problem, but they all require you to define identity sensibly. Only once that has been done can one begin the next step.

Comment: I'm not entirely satisfied with how I mixed `Tree` and `STRef` here. You'd probably want a specialized `Tree a` that had `STRef (Tree a)`s as children, so then you could replace whole subtrees. Here, I just made the labels `STRef`s since that's what worked better with `containers`, but you probably wouldn't want to do that in real life. (On the other hand, adding `STRef`s everywhere makes it very tedious to traverse.)